# Stack color scales asymptotes

Tags: asymptote

I'm pretty new to asymptote and I'm using it to make heat maps. 
I have my 2D data points, and let's say that their value range from *a* to *c*, and I have another intermediate value *b* in between.

I would like my values from *a* to *b* to be between blue and yellow and my values from *b* to *c* to be between yellow and red.

Does anyone know how to stack two palettes into one with these specific settings ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If b-a=c-b, then `pen[] Palette= Gradient(256,blue,yellow,red);` can help. See the documentation of `palette` and replace in the first example `pen[] Palette=BWRainbow();` by `pen[] Palette= Gradient(256,blue,yellow,red);`. If the range a,b,c is not uniform you have to construct by yourself such a color palette.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** : the first proposition was wrong, an error with the computations of step. Thanks to @Slvn for his comment and @Werner for the information.

In the case of a nonuniform gradient style palette, with 3 colors and range a,b,c please find the following code (in fact a modification of `image.asy`)
Please note that thanks to @Slvn the code has been modified.

```
  size(12cm,12cm);

  import graph;
  import palette;
  pen[] NonUniformThreeColorsGradient(int NColors=256,real a, real b, real c, pen p1, pen p2, pen p3) 
  {
    pen[] P;
    real step1=NColors > 1 ? ((c-a)/((b-a)*(NColors-1))) : 1;
    real step2=NColors > 1 ? ((c-a)/((c-b)*(NColors-1))) : 1;
    real step=NColors > 1 ? (1/(NColors-1)) : 1;
    pen begin=p1;
    pen end=p2;
    P.append(sequence(new pen(int j) {
            return interp(begin,end,j*step1);
          },(int) ((b-a)/(c-a)*NColors)));
    pen begin=p2;
    pen end=p3;
    P.append(sequence(new pen(int j) {
            return interp(begin,end,j*step2);
          },(int) ((c-b)/(c-a)*NColors)));
    return P;
  }

  int n=256;
  real ninv=2pi/n;
  real[][] v=new real[n][n];

  for(int i=0; i < n; ++i)
    for(int j=0; j < n; ++j)
      v[i][j]=3*sin(i*ninv)*cos(j*ninv);

  pen[] Palette= NonUniformThreeColorsGradient(256,-3,1,3,blue,yellow,red);
  //pen[] Palette= Gradient(256,blue,yellow,red);

  picture bar;

  bounds range=image(v,(0,0),(1,1), range=Range(-3,3), Palette);
  // Range(-3,3) forces to use [-3,3] as Range : useful in the case where
  // there is no data in [2.5;3] for example
  // see palette documentation for Full, Automatic, Range(min,max)
  palette(bar,"$A$",range,(0,0),(0.5cm,8cm),Right,Palette,
          PaletteTicks("$%+#.1f$"));
  add(bar.fit(),point(E),30E);
```

I hope that it is a correct answer (now it is correct?). Please find the result

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what I was asking for, thanks a lot @O.G. !

Comment: @O.G.: Apparently an update of your code is required. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415343/5764).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think there is a typo in your code @O.G.

```
pen[] NonUniformThreeColorsGradient(int NColors=256,real a, real b, real    c, pen p1, pen p2, pen p3) 
  {
pen[] P;
real step1=NColors > 1 ? ((c-a)/((b-a)*(NColors-1))) : 1;
real step2=NColors > 1 ? ((c-a)/((c-b)*(NColors-1))) : 1;
real step=NColors > 1 ? (1/(NColors-1)) : 1;
pen begin=p1;
pen end=p2;
P.append(sequence(new pen(int j) {
        return interp(begin,end,j*step1);
      },(int) ((b-a)/(c-a)*NColors)));
pen begin=p2;
pen end=p3;
P.append(sequence(new pen(int j) {
        return interp(begin,end,j*step2);
      },(int) ((c-b)/(c-a)*NColors)));
return P;
}
```

You did the other way around and therefore it did not work, but now it seems to be OK, thanks again !

Comment: I guess it's better to ping @O.G. and see if he can update his code...

Comment: @Slvn. You're right my code was wrong, a mistake in the steps computation.